# arc length to a straight line

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to draw a straight line of the same length as an arc, using compass and straightedge? Someone asked me this. I'm unable to figure out how this can be done.

Comment: By "arc," do you mean a portion of a *circle*?  ("Arc" sometimes refers to a section of any old curve.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If so, given a circle of radius 1, it would be possible to construct a straight line of length $2\pi$. But this is not possible because $\pi$ is transcendental and hence not constructible.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number) should be of interest